# KeyValue error when trying to convert datetime.datetime object using strftime in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, strptime, strftime

I'm attempting to convert values within a series from one datetime object format to another.

I've used the following to convert the original entry into a datetime object:

```
import datetime as dt
for each in DataFrame_name['Series_name']:
    DataFrame_name['Series_name'][each] = dt.datetime.strptime(each,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

This has been effective at converting string entries such as '2019-07-01 12:14' into datetime objects.

However, when I attempt to convert this datetime format to '%Y-%m', I get the a KeyError: datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 1, 12, 14)

```
for each in DataFrame_name['Series_name']:
    DataFrame_name['Series_name'][each].strftime('%Y-%m')
```

```
KeyError: datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 1, 0, 0)
```

Has anyone seen/solved this before?

Comment: [mcve] please. We need  ` DataFrame_name` definition (minimal data set needed to reproduce the issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take another, more *pandasonic* approach.

Assume that the source DataFrame is:

```
                Dat  Score
0  2019-07-01 12:14    120
1  2019-07-02 10:20    130
2  2019-08-07 18:33    610
```

where *Dat* column is kept as a *String* and *Score* as *int64* (as it could be
read from an Excel or CSV file).

To convert *Dat* column from *String* to *datetime*, instead of importing
*datetime* and your loop, just execute a **single** statement:

```
df.Dat = pd.to_datetime(df.Dat)
```

When you *print(df)*, you will get:

```
                  Dat  Score
0 2019-07-01 12:14:00    120
1 2019-07-02 10:20:00    130
2 2019-08-07 18:33:00    610
```

The type of *Dat* is now *datetime64[ns]* and the format it is printed
is as it is for *datetime* type.

Then, instead of reformatting it to text, convert it to *Period*
with *Month* frequency, again with a single instruction:

```
df.Dat = df.Dat.dt.to_period('M')
```

The result is:

```
       Dat  Score
0  2019-07    120
1  2019-07    130
2  2019-08    610
```

and the type of *Data* is *period[M]*.

Comment: Amazing thank you! That worked perfectly. I originally managed to find a solution using a for loop, but your method is much faster/simpler